# How to implement the "locked" feature in AWS/SQS when using Google Cloud Pub/Sub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, message-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

When you want to implement a producer/consumer pattern on top of Google Cloud Pub/Sub, you would expect each message can only be processed by one consumer. But Google Cloud Pub/Sub would send each message to all the subscribers.

But the AWS/SQS has the following feature to easy guarantee this:

> When a message is received, it becomes “locked” while being processed.
>   This keeps other computers from processing the message simultaneously.
>   If the message processing fails, the lock will expire and the message
>   will be available again. In the case where the application needs more
>   time for processing, the “lock” timeout can be changed dynamically via
>   the ChangeMessageVisibility operation.

How to implement the producer/consumer pattern on top of Google Cloud Pub/Sub? Or there is other alternative Google Cloud product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub has a similar mechanism. Keep in mind that not every *subscriber* will receive every message, every *subscription* will receive every message. The distinction is important. There can be multiple subscribers for a single subscription, pulling messages simultaneously and processing different messages for the same subscription simultaneously.

Within a single subscription, when a message is sent to a subscriber, it will not be sent to another subscriber for that subscription for the ack deadline specified at subscription creation time (default value is 10 seconds). The subscriber that receives the message has until the ack deadline to acknowledge the message or extend the ack deadline, which allows it to take longer to process the message without the message being delivered to other subscribers. Extending the ack deadline is handled automatically in some of the client libraries, e.g., [Java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/spi/v1/Subscriber.html) and [Go](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#Subscription.Pull), while others require the explicit modification of the ack deadline, e.g., [Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/pubsub-subscription.html#google.cloud.pubsub.subscription.Subscription.modify_ack_deadline). The ack deadline behaves the same way as SQS's visibility timeout.

See [message acknowledgement deadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#ack_deadline) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the classification, GCP should write better document, LOL

Comment: Pengdu the major issue with DataFlow and PubSub documentation is they don't talk about how these systems interact really. They also almost never cover the "next logical question". The documentation is alright, but it's just really disconnected.

Comment: @GL_Stephen no the documentation isnt clear. I have A subscription. I am using Go/Kub to launch subscribers which would pull message from same subscription. It seems like if I have 4 nodes running then they are ALL receiving message at the same time. That's odd, message shouldn't be seen by ALL of them at once.

Comment: @code-muncher Do you mean they all receive the *same* message at the same time or that they all receive some messages at the same time?

Comment: I deployed two (same) service with kube and they both had two pods running. Of course there were subscribed to same subscription. In my test I sent a message and they were received by all 4 pods in about same time. What I was hoping was that I would see one pod processing A msg and it will be "locked".

Comment: If they were all using the same subscription, then yes, the message would have most likely been sent to only a single subscriber unless the message had been outstanding long enough to one that the ack deadline expired and it needed to be redelivered or the pods were quickly nacking the messages. If that is not the behavior you are seeing, it is best to contact Google Cloud Support so they can get information about your topic, subscription, and message IDs for messages that were sent to all of your pods and look more deeply into the timing of deliveries.