# Visibility Timeout in Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm developing a message retry mechanism using Cloud Pub/Sub and Cloud Function with Pub/Sub trigger. I would like to know if I can set a visibility timeout(Just like in RabbitMQ) on a message in Cloud Pub/Sub so that it will be visible to my Cloud Function only after a certain time and gets processed? If not, What is the workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement the "locked" feature in AWS/SQS when using Google Cloud Pub/Sub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481523/how-to-implement-the-locked-feature-in-aws-sqs-when-using-google-cloud-pub-sub)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Cloud Pub/Sub has a feature called acknowledgement deadline which works similarly to visibility timeout.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/application-services#message_lifecycle) comparing Pub/Sub to Amazon SQS:

> Similarly, Pub/Sub has an acknowledgement deadline. By default, this deadline is 10 seconds, but it can be extended up to 10 minutes. For a pull subscription, subscribers can also modify the deadline on the fly on a per-message basis to allow for shorter or longer time to process a given message.